# How to access data from firestore using streambuilder flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access data from firestore but there are errors, how can i do that?
I cant use .docs in snapshot.

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: messageStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, top: 16),
                          reverse: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length, // error
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot ds =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index]; // error
                            return _buildMessage(
                                ds["message"], myUserName == ds["sendBy"]);
                          },
                        )
                      : Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                },
              ),
```

Stream:

```
getChatRoomMessages(chatRoomId) async {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("chatRooms").doc(chatRoomId).collection("chats").orderBy("ts", descending: true).snapshots();}
```

Comment: try this way and find out what the issue is.  `stream: getChatRoomMessages(id),`

Comment: 1) "but there are errors" In that case, please edit your question to include the exact error message, and the stack trace. 2) What is `messageStream` in the first snippet. Keep in mind that we can only see what you share, so the code you be as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 2):

in the StreamBuilder you have to use AsyncSnapshot in with your snapshot property. That was what got it working for me

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: DatabaseMethods().getChatRoomMessages(chatRoomId),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) { <<<< insert here
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, top: 16),
                          reverse: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length, // error
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot ds =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index]; // error
                            return _buildMessage(
                                ds["message"], myUserName == ds["sendBy"]);
                          },
                        )
                      : Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: DatabaseMethods().getChatRoomMessages(chatRoomId),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, top: 16),
                          reverse: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length, // error
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot ds =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index]; // error
                            return _buildMessage(
                                ds["message"], myUserName == ds["sendBy"]);
                          },
                        )
                      : Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                },
              ),
```